# Introduce local variable in Gogland ide

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland

How to introduce local variables in Gogland IDE in MacOS ??

I'm having the below code and want introduce the local variables for all the return values returned through `ParseKnowHosts` function.

```
authorizedKeyBytes, error := ioutil.ReadFile("authorized_keys")
if error != nil {
    log.Fatal(error)
}
ssh.ParseKnownHosts(authorizedKeyBytes) // returns <marker, hosts, key, pubKey, comment, rest>
```

What key supposed to use for automatically assign local variables to all returned values like below instead typing manually ? (I tried ALT + Enter didnt worked, which is the one I use for IntelliJ)

```
marker, hosts, key, pubKey, comment, rest := ssh.ParseKnownHosts(authorizedKeyBytes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CTRL+ALT+V for Windows / Linux (or CMD+ALT+V on OS X) or invoke the Refactor | Extract | Variable and then select the function call from the list and the variables will be inserted for you.